# Regex Match for Valid Dates only

Tags: regex, date

I am trying to create a regex that only matches for valid dates (in `MM/DD` or `MM/DD/YY(YY)` format)

My current regex `(\d+)/(\d+)/?(\d+)?` is very simple but it matches any number that has a `/` before/after. I.e. if a string is `2015/2016 12/25` it will see both of these as matches but i only want the `12/25` portion.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/pR8wD3/4) is a link to some sample RegEx.

Comment: Try [`(\d+)/(\d+)/?(\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/pR8wD3/3).

Comment: The dates are not always at end of string. They are surrounded by words

Comment: Then your approach is not correct. The regex matches what you ask it to match. You need to redefine the requirements.

Comment: Updated my regex in OP.

Comment: Ok, [`\b(\d{2})/(\d{2})/?(\d{4}|\d{2})?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/sL9kY6/1)?

Comment: Perfect! If you post it as answer i will accept. Btw for Month and day you want to do `\d{1,2}` since they can be 1 digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add word boundaries (`\b`) to make sure you match the date string as a whole "word" (so that the match does not start in the middle of a number) and restrict the occurrences `\d` matches with the help of limiting quantifiers:

```
\b(\d{2})/(\d{1,2})/?(\d{4}|\d{2})?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL9kY6/3)

The regex breakdown:

- `\b` - word boundary to make sure there is a non-word character or start of string right before the digit
- `(\d{2})` - match exactly 2 digits
- `/` - match a literal `/`
- `(\d{1,2})` - match and capture 1 to 2 digits
- `/?` - match 1 or 0 `/`
- `(\d{4}|\d{2})?` - match 1 or 0 occurrences of either 4 or 2 digits
- `\b` - trailing  word boundary